# What tools (high and low tech) can be used to find a foreign body (eg a splinter)?

Tags: medical-imaging, x-rays, ultrasounds, foreign-body-object

What are some tools that can be used to find a finding the exact location of a foreign body object inside someone?

I'm interested in both:

1. Low-tech tools that almost everyone in the world either [a] has access to or [b] can DIY build fairly trivially and
2. High-tech tools that only well-funded hospitals have access to

The `American Family Physician` VOLUME 67, NUMBER 1 published an article in June 2003 titled [Splinter Removal](https://www.aafp.org/dam/brand/aafp/pubs/afp/issues/2003/0615/p2557.pdf), which suggests a few high-tech imaging tools, including X-rays, Ultrasound, Xeroradiographs, CT scans, and MRIs.

But I could not find any reference to low-tech imaging tools to see the foreign body without a very, very expensive machine.

What are some tools that can be used in the field to find the exact location of a foreign body object for removal (eg a splinter buried in someone's foot for weeks/months).

Comment: See also https://www.aafp.org/pubs/afp/issues/2003/0615/p2557.html

Comment: Well, yes, table 3 in the linked page in your comment seems to about cover it. You are perfectly at liberty to provide a self-answer, we encourage self-learning here. It has the advantage that you can award yourself the accepted answer tick and bonus ;)

Comment: That link does provide everything needed for a good answer. If you're not going to write an answer, I suggest you add the link and a relevant quote from it to your question as prior research. Doing that will result in at least one downvote being removed.

Comment: I only see high-tech imaging tools in Table 3. Anyway, I added it to the question. Please remove the downvote.

Comment: The only "low tech" tools available are physical exam, and that's covered in table 2. I don't know what else you imagine might exist.

Comment: @MichaelAltfield low tech would be anything that can be used to physically touch the foreign body along with physical examination as per Carey Gregory's comments - be it needle, seeker, forceps etc. The list is almost impossibly long, depending on how low-tech you want to go (wooden toothpick? twig? cactus spine?, bone splinter...) and lists of this sort don't fit well with SE sites in general, partly through opinion based answers and "never able to answer fully" style answers.

Comment: Sorry, that seems very short-sighted. For example, if the flesh is thin enough, then a very bright light put behind the skin may help locate a foreign body object. I'm sure there are other such solutions that have been used historically before the discovery of the cathode ray tube..

Comment: @MichaelAltfield in that case, Are you asking what tools can be used to "see" a splinter rather than "find"? If so, then you are limited to visual light and the eye (+/- magnifying lenses) or a camera, or higher tech options such as X-ray, CT etc. Cathode ray tubes have been around since 1869, X-rays imaged in 1895. Arc lamps and gas lamps; 1800's. Oil lamps are 1780's. Prior to that it's candles or the sun...